# Django View Class

Tags: python, django

Below is the view function of the Django View Class

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    self = cls(**initkwargs)
    if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
        self.head = self.get
        self.request = request
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    view.view_class = cls
    view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
    update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
    update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
    return view
```

So Can any one please tell me why do we have below 2 attributes in that function?

```
view.view_class = cls
```

&

```
view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
```

Comment: I am not sure about it since I am not a Django user, but I guess it is only for some informative reasons. Knowing what class the specific view was created from and what arguments were passed to it might be useful in some cases.

Comment: I think you can find it in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)